# Why placeholder email seems to be necessary in Rails mailers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

I have a mailer in my Rails app, it looks like that:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "me@mydomain.com"
  def notification_email(notification)
    # ...
  end      
end
```

Furthermore, I have my `action_mailer` configured in `config/envionments/development.rb` file:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {  
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "mail.google.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: "my.real.email.address@sth.com",
  password: ENV['NOREPLY_EMAIL_PASSWORD']
}
```

So, after creating my `notification_email` and running `deliver`, it is sent from my `my.real.email.address@sth.com`, as I want. But what is strange, line `default :from => "me@mydomain.com"` still seems to be necessary, although this is a fake address: when I try to remove that, I get this error:

> SMTP From address may not be blank: nil

What is the reason of that strange behavior? Is the fake email address really necessary?

Comment: From address is required, but you can make it a real address like `my.real.email.address@sth.com`

Comment: So cannot I make it DRY, set in only one place? What's the reason of that while the email is overwritten later?

Comment: It's two different things... Your user name for your SMTP account, and your email address. They can be the same but don't have to be. And Gmail forces the from to be your Gmail address but other services let you set your own from address. The fact that Gmail overrides the from is a uniqueness of Gmail.

Comment: So, I should change that, because if when I change Gmail to other provider I can have problem, because it'll try to send it from my fake email, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you should use the from email that makes sense for the application's recipients.  My application default from is "(application_name) NO REPLY <no_reply.my_domain_name.com>" and that works, customers understand it.